# Import json URL to java and parse it using jackson library

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to read a json link in java and parse it so I can use it for other matters, but the problem is that I get errors that I really don't know waht to do about them.
Here is the code:

```
package weather.data;

import weather.data;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;
import java.io.IOException;

public class usertest {

    public static void main() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException 
    {

        URI jsonUrl = new URI("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/4b32c7ef1ceb5dd48bf5/raw/ef1987551faa3fb61473bb0e7aad70a228dc36d6/gistfile1.txt");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        City = mapper.readValue(jsonUrl, data.class);
    }

}
```

Here are the errors:
about import weather.data:Multiple markers at this line
    - Only a type can be imported. weather.data resolves to a 
     package
    - The import weather.data is never used

about City = mapper.readValue(jsonUrl, data.class):Multiple markers at this line
    - data cannot be resolved to a type
    - City cannot be resolved to a variable
    - The method readValue(JsonParser, Class) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the 
     arguments (URI, Class)
    - The method readValue(JsonParser, Class) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the 
     arguments (URI, Class)
    - City cannot be resolved to a variable
    - data cannot be resolved to a type

Any Ideas? Also I really do not understand the concept of using mapper.readValue. would any one help me please?

Note: I have used json gen to generate the data objects inside the link and now I have object data java files: City, Coord, List1, Temp and Weather with the following contents.

For City.java as a sample:

```
package weather.data;

import java.util.List;

public class City{
    private Coord coord;
    private String country;
    private Number id;
    private String name;
    private Number population;

    public Coord getCoord(){
        return this.coord;
    }
    public void setCoord(Coord coord){
        this.coord = coord;
    }
    public String getCountry(){
        return this.country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country){
        this.country = country;
    }
    public Number getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Number id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Number getPopulation(){
        return this.population;
    }
    public void setPopulation(Number population){
        this.population = population;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `import weather.data.City` (specific class) instead of `import weather.data` (a package).

And then do as @jdiver says:

```
City city = mapper.readValue(jsonUrl, City.class);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jcragun. I applied what you have said the first error about importing is gone but it still gives me this error for the second code: Multiple markers at this line - The method readValue(JsonParser, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (URI, Class<City>) - The method readValue(JsonParser, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (URI, Class<City>)

Comment: Use `java.net.URL` instead of `URI` class.

Comment: Sorry for late answer.I already have java.net.URI in my file.

Comment: UR **L** instead of **I**

Comment: Ohhh, stupid mistake. Thank you very much. It worked.

Comment: I have a new error: I get this message when I try to run the program:Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "cod" (class weather.data.City), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: , "coord", "country", "id", "name", "population"])
Any idea would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If `gistfile1.txt` file in the URL includes a JSON object of City, then replace the line

```
City = mapper.readValue(jsonUrl, data.class);
```

with

```
City = mapper.readValue(jsonUrl, City.class);
```

You should give object class to `readValue` method.

Comment: Thank you very much @jdiver. I applied what you have said but it still gives me this error: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method readValue(JsonParser, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the 
  arguments (URI, Class<City>)
 - The method readValue(JsonParser, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the 
  arguments (URI, Class<City>)