# How to receive Json data from Server URL?

Tags: java, json, gson, response, marshalling

I am trying to send json request using marshalling logic to server?
How to get json as response from server ? Do i have to parse it using below parser?

```
final SAXParserFactory sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
final SAXParser sp1 = sp.newSAXParser();
```

Comment: SAXParser is for XML not for JSON.
What do you really want to parse?

Maybe the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479332/import-json-url-to-java-and-parse-it-using-jackson-library will help.

Comment: @SirFartALot I want to get Json as response from server...That is my requirement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467568/parsing-json-from-url)

Comment: It depends from the libraries do you use. For example [`Spring` `RestTemplate`](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) call differs from [`Feign`](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-feign). See also: [How to use OpenFeign to get a pojo array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012543/how-to-use-openfeign-to-get-a-pojo-array), [Get list of JSON objects with Spring RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674046/get-list-of-json-objects-with-spring-resttemplate).

Answer (score 1):

The data format of the results depend on what your server response to you . you can translate the result string responsed by the server to pojo no mater the data format is xml  or json .

If data format is xml , you can use [JAXB](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) to translate it to pojo

If data format is json ,you can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to translate it to pojo

If you want to directly translte xml to json . Maybe [gson-xml](https://github.com/stanfy/gson-xml) library can help you.